# How do i create dynamic link in wordpress iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, date, url

I have a page with an iframe link to display page but the page content changes dynamically based on current date

http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=04/09/2014&querypage=49

now only thing in the URL that is changed every day is the date `04/09/2014` it will be `04/10/2014` on next day..

Can any one help this to change automatically based on current date?

I would be using `iframe src="http://www.dyanmic url" width="100%" height="1300"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `date()` function

```
http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.aspx?edcode=11&eddate=<?=date("d/m/Y")?>&querypage=49
```